# Engaging Screen Lock Notification

Tags: 16.04, notification, lock-screen

I am pretty new to linux, I recently installed 16.04. Slightly annoying issue I can't figure out. The screen locks when I am away, which is fine, but if I have been gone for a long period of time when I return there are multiple notifications stating "Engaging Screen Lock". When I say multiple I mean 60+ and I have to click on each individual black box to get rid of each notification.

Seems like an unnecessary notification, obviously I know my screen locked.  Once is fine, but 60+ times is too much.

Any help on how to turn off or reconfigure?

Thanks ahead of time!

Comment: Settings Manager -> Notifications from here you can change your settings